# Evitar envío de email de notificación desde pieza de formulario - BreezingForms

Tags: joomla3

Estamos utilizando BreezingForms para gestionar los formularios en nuestro sitio en Joomla

Hemos activado en la configuración del formulario la opción para las notificaciones por email.

Así mismo en el form tenemos un campo `correo`, al cual hemos activado la opción "Mailback" para el envío de email de respuesta una vez es llenado el formulario

Los emails de notificación se envían de forma correcta al admin y al usuario que envíaa los datos.

Ahora bien, hemos añadido una pieza de tipo `Inicio del envío` la cual se encarga de validar uno de los datos enviados mediante el formulario, y de existir no hace el registro de los datos enviados

Ahora bien me gustaría que en esta misma pieza podamos **EVITAR** que los mails de notificación configurados se envíen, cuando la condición que contemplamos para decir si se hace el registro o no, se cumplen

¿Es posible desde una pieza del formulario de BreezingForms evitar el envío de estos emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hemos logrado solventar dar con una solución.

Es bueno recordar que las piezas son código php por ende podemos utilizar cualquier funcion nativa que nos ayude a detener la ejecución de la petición actual, y en efecto así enfocamos nuestra solución.

En nuestra pieza al inicio de envío, como les comenté en mi pregunta, validamos si existe un registro en BD segun uno de los valores enviados desde el form.

Al momento de validar si la consulta retorna un registro, simplemente hemos añadido una redirección y una clausula exit

```
if($row){
    headers("Location:/path/to/new/location");
    exit();
}
```

De este modo hemos logrado que de existir el registro el formulario no ejecute el registro y los mails de notificación no sean enviados.

Igualmente BreezingForms posee ya una pieza creada en su librería standard llamada `ff_die` que podemos importar y usar en nuestras piezas para dar un funcioanlidad parecida, inclusive permite configurar el mensaje a mostrar y la pagina a la que redireccionara.

Espero les sea de ayuda